# Detect input button down state

Tags: javascript, html

How can I detect if the button below is currently pressed down (being held down)?

`<input type="button" value="Hold it down" id="aButton">`

To clarify, I don't mean to detect if the button is clicked, but being held down in the active state.

I tried to use the `mousedown` event but it doesn't work if the user operates the button with the keyboard, tabbing to the button and holding the space bar down.

Comment: try with `onmousedown` event

Comment: @DavorMlinaric I tried this already, I mentioned the flaw with this in my question, the problem is that the user can operate the button with the keyboard.

Comment: when a button is pressed, there will be a mouse event + (focus and active) classes will be attached to the button. When it's done via the keyboard, only the respective foucs and active classes will be added while there will be no mouse event. I wonder if  this can be used to determine a button press.

Answer (score 0):

It work fine with jquery `mousedown` (`onmousedown` in native js ) `mouseup` (`onmouseup` in native js ) events , bellow the working sample :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").on("mousedown",function(){
    console.log("btn click down using mouse");
  })
  var firstKeydown = true;
  $("#btn").on("keydown",function(e){
    if(e.which == 32){ // check if clicked button is sapcebar "code =32"
       if(firstKeydown) { // to prevent multiple firing 
          console.log("btn click down using keyboard");
          firstKeydown = false;
       }
    }
  })
  
  $("#btn").on("mouseup",function(){
    console.log("btn click up  using mouse");
  })

  $("#btn").on("keyup",function(e){
     if(e.which == 32) { // check if clicked button is sapcebar "code =32"
       console.log("btn click up using keyboard");
       firstKeydown =true;
     }
  }) 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Button</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, pressing the button down with the spacebar doesn't work for me. I'm using Chrome on a mac.

Comment: Does this make sens :)

Comment: Thanks, will accept if no one else posts a better solution. Just waiting a while to give people a chance to respond.

Comment: Great , thanks . yes may be there is a better way to catch input events !

Comment: Hey @Drahcir , I noticed a probleme when typing space , it was firing a multiple times when pressing the key continiously , so a added a check to prevent such a probleme , please see my updated answer